# How do I add an item size attribute to a product and make sure it's visible on search

Tags: product, magento-1.9, product-attribute, catalogsearch

I have a standard Magento 1.9 store with ~22000 products and use the default theme without customisations.

What I want to do is add item size information to a product. The item size may differ per product. For a yellow bell pepper it's going to be "each". For Ruffles Original party size potato chips it's going to be "13.5 oz".

I would like it to look like this:

[image: question]

My question has two parts:

1. What is the best way to add this type of attribute to a product?
2. How do I make sure it's visible in the search results when people search for a product?

Comment: This is actually a business question, no idea where to send these as SE only deals with tech. You create a new attibute either as a text field or as a dropdown, depending on how you do it and update the phtml. That's the simple way. You can also create a grouped layered nav attribute to for less granular searching.

Comment: serpyre... give you right process.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log into admin panel.

1. Go to `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes` and create a new attribute to keep your product sizes.
2. When you create the attribute make sure to set `Use Visible on Product View Page on Front-end` to `Yes`.
3. Go to `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attribute Sets` and assign the above created attribute in to the attribute set (which you have used to create products.)
4. Since you are using the default theme, you'll have to change the template file `frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog/product/list.phtml` in order to show the sizes in category pages.

> NOTE: In order to set the product sizes once you created the new
>   attribute, best thing you can do is write an external script to set
>   the values.

Comment: I'll be using Magmi to add/update ~22000 products on a daily basis. Will this work?

Comment: Does it allows to update attributes as well?

Comment: Yes, it does allow product attributes

Comment: What file do I have to edit to show the product size in the search too?

Comment: Then you need a data load tool, the simplest is Magmi or script (technical). We use enterprise grade which are onboarding tools (cleasing, mapping, enrichment) - which are cross techncial/business tools. Or you can use Excel and generates uploads (business) but that is time consuming

Comment: In order to show the attribute in search results you'll have to do some modifications in `frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog/product/list.phtml`

Comment: modifications means just echo the product attribute in that template